# C# Best practices for check objects and strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, object, empty-list

I work on Xamarin.Forms application and want to check all possible scenarios. For example i got this code:
 `User user= new User();   string token= string.Empty` i got a instance of object user and string token in the ViewModel's Constructor. I call them like this:

`user= await GetUser();token = await GetToken();`
I want to check every possible return from this calls. For object check if is empty , is null or got data. for string is empty , is null or got data ? Also hint for array of object? How to organize this?

Comment: You should read [ask]. If you can improve your question it can be re-opened.

Comment: A string value may be `null`, may contain some text, or may be empty, which is a string instance contaning no characters (`""`). But you might also consider  "only whitespace" to be  "empty" in your particular usecase. A variable of type User may be `null` or contain some instance. But it is up to you to define an "empty User", if that is even possible. In short, there is no general way to define an "empty instance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They return what you have defined in the method definition.
The following

```
Task<ReturnType> GetUser()
```

returns an object of type `ReturnType`.

To compare if an object is null:
`user == null`.
To compare if a string is null or empty:
`string..IsNullOrEmpty(<yourstring>)`

I suggest you to study OOP in C#

Comment: can u check Empty Object in C#?

Comment: What do you mean for "empty"?